# Where is my Bosal Oris detachable Tow bar hidden in my Mercedes ml500 2005?

Tags: mercedes-benz, towing

There is a inner panel on the rear right side of the car where the jack and triangle is stored but the detachable ball is wedged into polystyrene and i cant seem to pry it out. Are there any clips or screws the i need to be aware of or should i just pull harder?